# How to downgrade/rollback migration in Universal Windows Platform with Entity Framework using Package Manager Console?

Tags: entity-framework, migration, win-universal-app

I modified a property in the model and it turned out it is not supported by the version of SQLite. This is the error. `{"SQLite does not support this migration operation ('DropColumnOperation'). For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723262."}`

So I decided to roll it back by using the command `Update-Database Migration "MyFirstMigration"` but an error shows up on the console which states `Update-Database shouldn't be used with Universal Windows Platform apps. Instead, call DbContext.Database.Migrate() at runtime.`. This code recommended is already the code executed at the first run of the application that generates the first error above.

I am really going into circle here. Can someone suggest how I can rollback/downgrade `MySecondMigration` ti `MyFirstMigration`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone suggest how I can rollback/downgrade MySecondMigration ti MyFirstMigration?

For the same `DbContext`, just execute `Remove-Migration` command on your package manager console, it will remove the last migration of this `DbContext`. It is your `MySecondMigration` which will be removed and only `MyFirstMigration` left.

> Update-Database shouldn't be used with Universal Windows Platform apps. Instead, call DbContext.Database.Migrate() at runtime

For this, just as this error shown, `DbContext.Database.Migrate()` applies any pending migrations for the context to the database, include what `Update-Database` did (Updates the database to a specified migration). By testing on my side, for the same `DbContext`, every new migration is the updating based on the old one. `DbContext.Database.Migrate()` will apply all the migrations for updating. If you don't want the latest update, just remove it for roll back.